# Tag doesn't reach Google Analytics if matched with specific trigger

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using the data layer to fire events on an ecommerce website and send this info to 3rd parties (Pixel, UA, GA4). The mystery appears when a specific tag that is supposed to send the event to Google Universal Analytics doesn't communicate when matched with the Purchase event.

This trigger is working because it's showing activity on the preview/debug mode, in Facebook Pixel and Google Analytics 4 dashboards, but not on UA.

If I change the trigger to page view, for example, it shows on UA. Already deleted and tried a new tag, changed all the event values. Double-checked the ID. There's other 3 similar tags with different triggers (add to cart, etc) that are working properly.

With the tests I've made, it seems that the tag works properly as well the trigger. But when I match both in the same tag, it doesn't work. Nothing shows on Events (past or real-time) of GA.

What could it be?

Here is the purchase event code:

```
{
event: "Purchase",
ecommerce: {
    purchase: {
        transaction_id: "567976",
        affiliation: "dasdsd",
        value: 76.9,
        shipping: 0,
        tax: 14.38,
        currency: "EUR",
        coupon: "",
        items: [
            {
                id: 312312,
                name: "asdf",
                category: "asdf",
                brand: "asdf",
                variant: "",
                price: 76.9,
                quantity: 1
            }
        ]
    }
},
gtm.uniqueEventId: 5
}
```

Comment: It's just a normal purchase data layer event. I think the inside code is irrelevant as long as the event fires, and it does. The problem is when is matched with a certain type of tag. Added it anyway. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I was expecting code like `ga('send', 'event', 'Video', 'play', 'cats.mp4');` which is the usual way to send events to UA.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits

Comment: Yea, normally I use Tag Manager to make that communication.